# How to get number of consumers connected to ActiveMQ using Java & JMX?

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I need to write a program where it should check the number of consumers post restarting a *TASK*, ActiveMQ and ActiveMQ web service. The restarting of services happens with a script at particular time. After restart, my program which would be configured as task in scheduler has to check the number of consumers. I tried writing the following program, but it throws:

```
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException Caused by: javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost,destinationType=Queue at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1095)
```

What is wrong in this?

```
public void getStatistics() throws Exception {
    JMXServiceURL jmxServiceURL = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi");
    JMXConnector jmxConnector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(jmxServiceURL, null);
    jmxConnector.connect();
    MBeanServerConnection serverConnection = jmxConnector.getMBeanServerConnection();
    ObjectName objectName = new ObjectName("org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost," +
            "destinationType=Queue");
    BrokerViewMBean viewMBean = MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(serverConnection, objectName,
            BrokerViewMBean.class, true);
    System.out.println("Statistics for broker " + viewMBean.getBrokerId() + " - " +
            viewMBean.getBrokerName());
    System.out.println("\n---------------\n");
    System.out.println("Total messages count: " + viewMBean.getTotalMessageCount());
    System.out.println("Total number of consumers: " + viewMBean.getTotalConsumerCount());
    System.out.println("Total number of queues: " + viewMBean.getQueues().length);

    for (ObjectName queueName: viewMBean.getQueues()) {
        QueueViewMBean queueViewMBean = MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(serverConnection, queueName
                , QueueViewMBean.class, true);
        System.out.println("\n---------------\n");
        System.out.println("Statistics for queue: " + queueViewMBean.getName());
        System.out.println("Size: " + queueViewMBean.getQueueSize());
        System.out.println("Number of consumers: " + queueViewMBean.getConsumerCount());
    }
}
```

Added activemq.xml

```
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
    contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
    this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
    The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
    (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
    the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- START SNIPPET: example -->
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <!-- Allows us to use system properties as variables in this configuration file -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <value>file:${activemq.conf}/credentials.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

   <!-- Allows accessing the server log -->
    <bean id="logQuery" class="io.fabric8.insight.log.log4j.Log4jLogQuery"
          lazy-init="false" scope="singleton"
          init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    </bean>

    <!--
        The <broker> element is used to configure the ActiveMQ broker.
    -->
    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}">

        <destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
              <policyEntries>
                <policyEntry topic=">" >
                    <!-- The constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy is used to prevent
                         slow topic consumers to block producers and affect other consumers
                         by limiting the number of messages that are retained
                         For more information, see:

                         http://activemq.apache.org/slow-consumer-handling.html

                    -->
                  <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                    <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
                  </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                </policyEntry>
              </policyEntries>
            </policyMap>
        </destinationPolicy>


        <!--
            The managementContext is used to configure how ActiveMQ is exposed in
            JMX. By default, ActiveMQ uses the MBean server that is started by
            the JVM. For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html
        -->
        <managementContext>
            <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
        </managementContext>

        <!--
            Configure message persistence for the broker. The default persistence
            mechanism is the KahaDB store (identified by the kahaDB tag).
            For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/persistence.html
        -->
        <persistenceAdapter>
            <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/>
        </persistenceAdapter>


          <!--
            The systemUsage controls the maximum amount of space the broker will
            use before disabling caching and/or slowing down producers. For more information, see:
            http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html
          -->
          <systemUsage>
            <systemUsage>
                <memoryUsage>
                    <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70" />
                </memoryUsage>
                <storeUsage>
                    <storeUsage limit="100 gb"/>
                </storeUsage>
                <tempUsage>
                    <tempUsage limit="50 gb"/>
                </tempUsage>
            </systemUsage>
        </systemUsage>

        <!--
            The transport connectors expose ActiveMQ over a given protocol to
            clients and other brokers. For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html
        -->
        <transportConnectors>
            <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        </transportConnectors>

        <!-- destroy the spring context on shutdown to stop jetty -->
        <shutdownHooks>
            <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" class="org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook" />
        </shutdownHooks>

    </broker>

    <!--
        Enable web consoles, REST and Ajax APIs and demos
        The web consoles requires by default login, you can disable this in the jetty.xml file

        Take a look at ${ACTIVEMQ_HOME}/conf/jetty.xml for more details
    -->
    <import resource="jetty.xml"/>

</beans>
<!-- END SNIPPET: example -->
```

Comment: Can you add your broker's `activemq.xml` file?

Answer (score 0):

According to the exception the `ObjectName` you're using is incorrect. Try this instead:

```
ObjectName objectName = new ObjectName("org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost");
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried using JMX but I get a different error not able to figure out where is the issue. Can you please help?

Comment: I added org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost initially, that gave me the same error. So I tried adding destinationType along with it. I get the same error for both values. Is there anything else I need to change?

Comment: Perhaps your broker is using a different name. Can you connect to the broker via JConsole and find the broker's JMX object name?

Comment: It is org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost

Comment: Using... -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false